# Open shapefile from S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, geodjango

I need to store couple large shapefiles (2 GB) in S3 bucket, and from that made calculations in the backend side writen in Django.

Shapefiles will be not stored at database models. Downloading those to the filesystem every time calculations will be made is quite bad idea.

So I'm looking a way to open shp files in Django app, without downloading those directly fto FS, like in `rasterio` lib.

Is there any lib that could be utilized for that, or do you know a solution for this problem?

Comment: Will it make sense to automatically split the shapefiles into smaller ones?  See also my better solution below.

Comment: Will this help: http://andrewgaidus.com/Reading_Zipped_Shapefiles/ ?

Comment: or this: http://geospatialpython.com/2011/09/reading-shapefiles-from-cloud.html ?

Comment: @Udi I was thinking before about creating another database just for storing the shapefiles. But most of my raster layers are in S3 bucket, so I would like to have files in one place. I will check your link about reading shapefiles from the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

If your have a lot of vector data, create another DB for storing it (preferably postgis), and use [LayerMapping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/layermapping/) to copy it there by using a decent Django model.  (Bonus: fix your data and create indexes while copying).

Use [geoqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/) to retrieve the parts of the data you need for your calculations.

Django can connect to [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/), so you don't have to keep all of this data in your main (default) database.